# I'm copying all httpdocs files from server to server using rsync, what do I use to include hidden / htaccess files

Tags: linux, bash

Here is the command I'm running

```
rsync -av -e ssh httpdocs user@ipaddress:httpdocs
```

but that misses out hidden files like .htaccess ?

Any help appreciated !

Rich :)

Comment: I test it under linux (but only a local copy with rsync) and hidden files are also copied. Can your ssh user read the .htaccess files?

Comment: What result brings a call like that: ssh user@ipaddress cat PATH_TO_DOR_HTACCESS

Comment: Hmm i've just looked again and it had missed it on some domains.. maybe permission like you say, its' ok on another one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With rsync all subdirectories and files will be automaticaly copied. You need not additional keys or options to copy hidden files.